# Facebook graph api gives empty result for likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying my first very basic Facebook app using php and have stumbled upon a bit of a problem.

When being authenticated i can easily enough use the graph api to get information about my account...

```
$movies = $facebook->api('/me');
echo 'Me';
debug($movies);
```

which results in a nice array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1000....
    [name] => ...
    [first_name] => ...
    [last_name] => ...
    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000...
    [gender] => male
    [timezone] => 2
    [locale] => de_DE
    [verified] => 1
    [updated_time] => 2011-04-13T09:27:42+0000
)
```

I also can easily enough get a list of all my friends by using...

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
echo 'Friends:';
debug($friends);
```

But when I try to get my likes ...

```
$likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
echo 'Likes:';
debug($likes);
```

...all I get is an empty result:

```
Likes:

Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

When I use the demonstration link from the [graph api page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) it displays my likes just fine, but not from inside my app.

Anybody has an idea why that might be? As far as I could find out there is no need for extra permission to get the likes of a logged in user, basic permissions should suffice?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Requires the `user_likes` or `friends_likes` permission to get the list of your / friends likes...

I think you forgot to get those permissions... :)

Comment: Damn, you are right - you need the user_likes permission. But i've seen many an app that knew if I liked the site I was on, without needing extra permissions?! How do they do that?

Comment: They all are using FQL, i think.. :)